# How to add multiple column to slicer in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

How can we show multiple columns into one slicer? Let's say I have three columns - `product category`, `product` and `type`. I want display three columns into one slicer.

How can I do this in Power BI Desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go to your data model and add a new calculated column to the relevant table that concatenates the three columns.  Use this new column as the field in your slicer.

```
SlicerData = [column1] & ", " & [column2] & ", " & [column3]
```

However, in most cases you get a lot more flexibility by having three different slicers, one for each column.  Not to mention three slicers with 10 items each is much more convenient than one slicer with 1000 items.